# Re-streaming RTMP to RTSP

Tags: rtsp, rtmp

I have some trouble with RTMP and RTSP protocol.

I have a Gopro action cam with RTMP output stream. But input of my algorithm compressor need RTSP stream.

I found Wowza solution can transcode from RTMP to RTSP but it very expensive.

How can I convert RTMP to RTSP?